# Ruby and Xcode - wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, rvm, homebrew

http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/#step-2

I used this tutorial to install Homebrew and everything that comes with him. It's all good and I have a version **ruby-2.0.0-p353**.

Now I have a Xcode app that uses Localization shell script and I come upon a problem :
`System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in gem_original_require: no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)`

I know I installed 2.0.0 and I checked in Terminal.

```
Spires-Mac-Pro:~ spire$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

But Xcode says Version 1.8? Then by luck/accident I started Xcode from Terminal

`open -a Xcode`

It worked, on my surprise

So now whenever I start Xcode from terminal, it compiles OK with ruby 2.0.0 but if I start Xcode from Applications it shows the version 1.8 and error.

Can someone help me fix this problem,what's wrong, It's frustrating?

P.S. I've done `rvm use 2.0.0 --default`

Comment: This question might provide a lead [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776319/how-to-make-xcode-use-the-correct-version-of-ruby-when-running-a-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776319/how-to-make-xcode-use-the-correct-version-of-ruby-when-running-a-script)

Comment: @AGS as I can see here the person decided to not spent his time on fixing it, so can you confirm a fix? Which one is it?