# Is there any way to ask RVM for current Ruby path?

Tags: ruby, xcode, rvm

I am trying to ask RVM for current Ruby path, to call it from bash. This happens in Xcode environment, where `ruby` is Xcode's one, but I wanna to solve it like this (just example, not really works):

```
$(rvm which) my-script.rb
```

Help me to ask RVM for current Ruby path :)

Comment: Where have you searched and what did you read? Did you read through https://rvm.io/integration? We need you to tell us what you tried and where you looked, otherwise we'll suggest things that could be duplicates of your effort, which wastes both our times. "[ask]" and the linked pages talk about this.

Comment: @theTinMan I have read `man` and some docs in web, but found only `rvm environment` command, it contains info I need, but it is not simple to extract this info directly.

Comment: @k06a is my post helpful?

Comment: @smefju sorry, but no. My problem is to make Xcode to use RVM's Ruby instead of it's own Ruby version.

Comment: take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776319/how-to-make-xcode-use-the-correct-version-of-ruby-when-running-a-script

Answer (score 2):

You can use `which ruby`. It will point to the binary from currently used Ruby. Take a look at this page: https://rvm.io/rvm/basics.

You should also take a look at this topic: [How to make xcode use the correct version of ruby when running a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776319/how-to-make-xcode-use-the-correct-version-of-ruby-when-running-a-script)