# Xcode run phase script in Ruby wrong encoding

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, fastlane

I am trying to integrate ruby script (fastlane tool) and call it in run phase in xcode, something like this:

```
fastlane xcode_run_phase
```

It runs well in my terminal, but in xcode I get the following error :

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fastlane-1.53.0/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:20:in
>   `tr!': incompatible character encodings: US-ASCII and UTF-8
>   (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

Xcode is running it in some weird mode, which breaks ruby encoding. I tried forcing

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

or forcing different rvm like here: [Use rvm to force specific Ruby in Xcode Run Script build phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474902/use-rvm-to-force-specific-ruby-in-xcode-run-script-build-phase) 
with no luck.

Any idea how to force xcode to run the script in normal mode, like in terminal?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone can solve? I got that when I run from jenkin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the solution seems to be to force UTF8 onto ruby

```
LC_ALL= LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ruby -e 'p Encoding.default_external'
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```